# How to define variable in range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I just started VBA coding and I am struck here:

For one cell this program works:

```
Dim score As Integer, result As String

score = Range("A1").Value

If score >= 60 Then

    result = "pass"

Else
    result = "fail"

End If

Range("B1").Value = result
```

And how about a column of cells? Can loop works for this? 
My code using loop - **But How to define variable in range?**

```
Dim score As Integer, result As String, I As Integer

score = Range("AI").Value

For I = 1 To 6

If score >= 60 Then

result = "pass"

Else

    result = "fail"

End If
Range("BI").Value = result

Next I
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost, you just need to use string concatenation (`&`)

```
Dim score As Integer, result As String, I As Integer

'score = Range("AI").Value

For I = 1 To 6

    score = Range("A" & I).Value '// Needs to be inside the loop to update.

    If score >= 60 Then
        result = "pass"
    Else
        result = "fail"
    End If

    Range("B" & I).Value = result

Next I
```

This can also be written as:

```
For i = 1 To 6
    Range("B" & i).Value = IIf(Range("A" & i).Value >= 60, "pass", "fail")
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also go with a "formula" approach:

```
Range("B1:B6").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(RC1 >= 60, ""pass"", ""fail"")"
```

thus maintaining that check active for any possible subsequent change in columns A cells values

or, should you want to have "static" values only:

```
With Range("B1:B100")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=If(RC1 >= 60, ""pass"", ""fail"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: it's the same, since values to check are in column "A" which is column 1